# Difference between reduce task and a reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, reducers, bigdata

"a reducer is different than a reduce task. A reducer can run multiple reduce tasks". Can someone explain this with the below example?

foo.txt: Sweet, this is the foo file
bar.txt: This is the bar file

and I am using 2 reducers. What are the reduce tasks and based on what multiple reduce tasks are generated in a reducer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Reducer*** is a class, which contain *reduce* function as below

```
protected void reduce(KEYIN key, Iterable<VALUEIN> values, Context context
                        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
```

***Reduce task*** is program running on a node, which is executing **reduce** function of **Reducer** class.

You can think ***Reduce task*** as an instance of ***Reducer***

Have a look at Apache [MapReduce](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) tutorial page for more details ( **Payload**  section).

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, Reducer is a slot of computational resource, that can be used to accomplish reduce tasks. A reducer can be assigned to a task, which it performs to completion/failure and as soon as the task reaches an end-state, it is available for processing another reduce task, post-cleanup.

In Yarn, the concepts are a bit different though.

Answer (score 2):

The reducer is the code you are writing (or reusing) to process the data coming in.

The reduce task is the actual *instantiation* of a reducer code that runs on a node in your cluster. This task has a state machine and might fail. In case of failure another reduce task is spun up to restart the computation. This is called reduce task *attempt*. There is a finite number of retries to restart the computation ("maximum amount of attempts").

You can configure `n` reducers (as in reduce tasks), which is the maximum amount of parallel reduce tasks that might happen at any point in time of the job execution (set aside speculative execution).

Comment: Quoting Retry mechanism in answer is useful

Comment: You mean to say that each reducer is meant to execute one reduce task if it does not fail, right!!                           
For the example I took, 1st reduce task will produce: 

bar 1  
file 2
foo 1   
is 2

And the second reduce task will produce: 

sweet 1
the 2
this 2

Please confirm if I am correct